# Renaming index yields "Error: cross-database references are not implemented"

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have an index `badName` on table `tableName` inside `schemaName`, created like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX badName ON schemaName.tableName USING btree;
```

Now I want to rename the index to `goodName`. This is my attempt at it:

```
ALTER INDEX schemaName.tableName.badName RENAME TO goodName;
```

Which results in:

```
Error [0A000] cross-database references are not implemented
```

I am using postgresql database, but want to use native SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify (only) the index name, not the table name:

```
ALTER INDEX schemaname.badname RENAME TO goodname;
```